# render seo meta tags on server with servicestack angular 2 template

Tags: angular, servicestack

Servicestack angular 2 template have only one entry point - inxed.html.
Let's say we want to have seo meta tags rendered on server for SEO optimization for route like /product/id. Any ideas how to make it?

Comment: For optimized seo ,use Angular Universal

Comment: angular universal have tons of issues for now and page response time is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ServiceStack's [Single Page App templates](http://docs.servicestack.net/templates-single-page-apps) as the name suggests only runs from a single server [index.html](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Templates/blob/master/src/SinglePageApps/Angular4App/Angular4App/index.html) page. This means that all the routing are performed on the client (i.e. browser) in Angular JS.

This means that when the client navigates to a different page on the website, e.g. to `/products/1` the request is handled by Angular client-side routing to load the configured component, i.e. the request never reaches the server.

But when an initial request is made to `/products/1`, the request is sent to the server, but in order for Angular to be able to handle the routing on the client, ServiceStack returns the `index.html` home page, which it does for any unmatched requests using a [FallbackRoute](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#fallback-route) that's configured in the Template's [MyServices class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Templates/blob/master/src/SinglePageApps/Angular4App/Angular4App.ServiceInterface/MyServices.cs), e.g

```
[Exclude(Feature.Metadata)]
[FallbackRoute("/{PathInfo*}")]
public class FallbackForClientRoutes
{
    public string PathInfo { get; set; }
}

public class MyServices : Service
{
    //Return index.html for unmatched requests so routing is handled on client
    public object Any(FallbackForClientRoutes request) =>
        new HttpResult(VirtualFileSources.GetFile("index.html"));
}
```

In order to be able to return a modified `index.html` page you can just create a route that matches the request you want to handle, e.g:

```
[Exclude(Feature.Metadata)] //Hide Route from metadata pages
[Route("/product/{Id}")]
public class ViewProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

and return a modified `index.html` page replacing a place holder in your page with the metadata you want, e.g:

```
[AddHeader(ContentType = MimeTypes.Html)]
public object Any(ViewProduct request)
{
    var indexFile = VirtualFileSources.GetFile("index.html");
    var html = indexFile.ReadAllText();
    return html.Replace("meta name=\"description\"", 
       $"meta name=\"description\" content=\"Product #{request.Id}\"");
}
```

To tell Webpack to include your custom place holder when it generates the `index.html` you need to modify the [index.template.ejs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Templates/blob/master/src/SinglePageApps/Angular4App/Angular4App/index.template.ejs) template, e.g:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description">
 ...
```